# Is a set of circles in $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that no two circles (not discs) overlap necessarily countable or possibly uncountable?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, first-countable

Is a set of circles in $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that no two circles (not discs) overlap necessarily countable or possibly uncountable?

Answer (score 3):

If you take all the circles with a center $(0,0)$ you have an uncountable set of circles that do not overlap (i.e. have pairwise empty intersection). Thus such a set does not need to be countable.